# Changes in plotting an XTS object

Tags: r, plot, xts, zoo

I had produced the following chart, which is created using an xts object.

[image]

The code I used was simply

```
   plot(graphTS1$CCLL, type = "l", las = 2, ylab = "(c)\nCC for Investors", xlab = "", main = "Clustering Coefficient at the Investor Level")
```

I updated my R Studio Package and R version and then by running the same code I got the following chart.

[image]

Obviously the two are not the same. Can people help me remove the second Y axis - I do not need that, and remove the automatic heading of 2007-03-01 / 2010-12-01. Numerous attempts of this have failed. I did use zoo.plot but the gridlines and ability and the quarterly marks were removed.

My R version is 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) with the following platform "x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You want to remove the right hand axis. There is an argument in `plot.xts(..., yaxis.right = TRUE, ...)`. So

```
library('xts')
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')

plot(sample.xts, yaxis.right = FALSE)
```

[image]

does what you want.

I took a stab at solving the second question, removing the label at the top right hand side. Examining the source code for `plot.xts()` reveals that label is hardcoded into the main title. Even setting `main = ''` isn't going to remove it. You can work around it by editing `plot.xts()` and copying it to a new function.

```
plotxts <- fix("plot.xts")
# In the editor that opens, replace the lines below:
###    text.exp <- c(expression(text(xlim[1], 0.5, main, font = 2, 
###        col = theme$labels, offset = 0, cex = 1.1, pos = 4)), 
###        expression(text(xlim[2], 0.5, paste(start(xdata[xsubset]), 
###            end(xdata[xsubset]), sep = " / "), col = theme$labels, 
###            adj = c(0, 0), pos = 2)))
###    cs$add(text.exp, env = cs$Env, expr = TRUE)
# with these lines:
###    text.exp <- expression(text(xlim[1], 0.5, main, font = 2,
###        col = theme$labels, offset = 0, cex = 1.1, pos = 4))

# Finally, you need to ensure your copy's environment is the xts namespace:
environment(plotxts) <- asNamespace("xts")

plotxts(sample.xts, yaxis.right = FALSE, main = "Main Title")
```

The second, and perhaps
simpler option is to use a different plot function and modify it to produce the gridlines etc that you want. I will start
with `plot.zoo()` because it is already handling time series nicely.

```
zoo::plot.zoo(sample.xts, screens = 1, xlab="", las=2, main="Main Title")
grid() # add the grid
```

[image]

That at least gets the grid on there. I can't test if it will handle the x axis labels the same way without data at the right frequency.

Comment: Thank you for answering this for me, and sorry for the belated acknowledgment. In the short-term I will go with option 2 but will look to utilize the first option down the track.

Comment: `fix()`...this changes everything

Answer (score 3):

You can now (finally) omit the date range from the plot in xts 0.12.2 on CRAN. Set `main.timespan = FALSE`.

```r
plot(sample.xts[,1], yaxis.right = FALSE, main = "Main Title", main.timespan = FALSE)
```

[image]