# quantmod::chart_Series() how to simplify x-axis labels?

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

What is the proper way to remove the bottom portion of the x-axis labels for chart_Series()? 
eg. I would like to remove "Jan 03 2007 ... Oct 19 2018", but leave the years above the x-axis.

github link: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/262

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("BRS")
pdf("foo.pdf")
par(mfrow = c( 4, 2 ) )
chart_Series(BRS)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Some other notes:

1. The top of the chart is slightly cut off

2. The data line crosses the x-axis labels making it hard to read 2017

3. I would like to format the upper right labels to use '.' instead of '-'

Comment: That Github link has some solutions to your question. At least regarding the x-axis. Are they not adequate enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it. First of all, the top right text is hard coded so you need to alter the function in order to fix this. On your console type:

```
plotquant <- fix("chart_Series")
```

and in the editor change the following (~line 118) :

```
 text.exp <- c(expression(text(1 - 1/3, 0.5, name, font = 2, 
    col = "#444444", offset = 0, cex = 1.1, pos = 4)), expression(text(NROW(xdata[xsubset]), 
    #the line you need to change is below
    0.5, paste(start(xdata[xsubset]), end(xdata[xsubset]), 
      sep = " / "), col = 1, adj = c(0, 0), pos = 2)))
```

Into:

```
 text.exp <- c(expression(text(1 - 1/3, 0.5, name, font = 2, 
    col = "#444444", offset = 0, cex = 1.1, pos = 4)), expression(text(NROW(xdata[xsubset]), 
    0.5, paste(format(start(xdata[xsubset]), format = '%Y.%m.%d'), 
               format(end(xdata[xsubset]), format = '%Y.%m.%d'), 
      sep = " / "), col = 1, adj = c(0, 0), pos = 2)))
```

Then set the function into the correct namespace (so it works normally within quantmod) and also remove the labels with the chart elements as mentioned on the github link:

```
environment(plotquant) <- asNamespace("quantmod")
ct <- chart_theme()
ct$format.labels <- ' '
```

Then you are ready to plot:

```
plotquant(BRS, theme = ct)
```

[image]

As for your points 1 and 2, I think it is because you use `par(mfrow...` which changes the margins of the plots (making all of them the same size). In my picture you can see that it looks great. You could use `layout` instead of `par(mfrow...` to set your own sizes. Check `?layout`.

Some Credit:

Got a lot of help from this answer:

[Changes in plotting an XTS object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051076/changes-in-plotting-an-xts-object)

Update

The whole process can be replicated anywhere. We only create the function `plotquant` once. (actually here we don't edit the file, we just create a new function based on one that exists already i.e. `chart_Series`). Then once we have `plotquant` we are ready to create a script with everything included.

Type `plotquant` on the console and the source code will be revealed. Copy paste that into your script and you have defined your function. Then the rest follows normally:

```
plotquant <- function (x, name = deparse(substitute(x)), type = "candlesticks", 
  subset = "", TA = "", pars = chart_pars(), theme = chart_theme(), 
  clev = 0, ...) 
{
  cs <- new.replot()
  line.col <- theme$col$line.col
  up.col <- theme$col$up.col
  dn.col <- theme$col$dn.col
  up.border <- theme$col$up.border
  dn.border <- theme$col$dn.border
  format.labels <- theme$format.labels
  if (is.null(theme$grid.ticks.on)) {
    xs <- x[subset]
    major.grid <- c(years = nyears(xs), months = nmonths(xs), 
      days = ndays(xs))
    grid.ticks.on <- names(major.grid)[rev(which(major.grid < 
      30))[1]]
  }
  else grid.ticks.on <- theme$grid.ticks.on
  label.bg <- theme$col$label.bg
  cs$subset <- function(x) {
    if (FALSE) {
      set_ylim <- get_ylim <- set_xlim <- Env <- function() {
      }
    }
    if (missing(x)) {
      x <- ""
    }
    Env$xsubset <<- x
    set_xlim(c(1, NROW(Env$xdata[Env$xsubset])))
    ylim <- get_ylim()
    for (y in seq(2, length(ylim), by = 2)) {
      if (!attr(ylim[[y]], "fixed")) 
        ylim[[y]] <- structure(c(Inf, -Inf), fixed = FALSE)
    }
    lapply(Env$actions, function(x) {
      frame <- abs(attr(x, "frame"))
      fixed <- attr(ylim[[frame]], "fixed")
      if (frame%%2 == 0 && !fixed) {
        lenv <- attr(x, "env")
        if (is.list(lenv)) 
          lenv <- lenv[[1]]
        min.tmp <- min(ylim[[frame]][1], range(na.omit(lenv$xdata[Env$xsubset]))[1], 
          na.rm = TRUE)
        max.tmp <- max(ylim[[frame]][2], range(na.omit(lenv$xdata[Env$xsubset]))[2], 
          na.rm = TRUE)
        ylim[[frame]] <<- structure(c(min.tmp, max.tmp), 
          fixed = fixed)
      }
    })
    set_ylim(ylim)
  }
  environment(cs$subset) <- environment(cs$get_asp)
  if (is.character(x)) 
    stop("'x' must be a time-series object")
  if (is.OHLC(x)) {
    cs$Env$xdata <- OHLC(x)
    if (has.Vo(x)) 
      cs$Env$vo <- Vo(x)
  }
  else cs$Env$xdata <- x
  cs$Env$xsubset <- subset
  cs$Env$cex <- pars$cex
  cs$Env$mar <- pars$mar
  cs$set_asp(3)
  cs$set_xlim(c(1, NROW(cs$Env$xdata[subset])))
  cs$set_ylim(list(structure(range(na.omit(cs$Env$xdata[subset])), 
    fixed = FALSE)))
  cs$set_frame(1, FALSE)
  cs$Env$clev = min(clev + 0.01, 1)
  cs$Env$theme$bbands <- theme$bbands
  cs$Env$theme$shading <- theme$shading
  cs$Env$theme$line.col <- theme$col$line.col
  cs$Env$theme$up.col <- up.col
  cs$Env$theme$dn.col <- dn.col
  cs$Env$theme$up.border <- up.border
  cs$Env$theme$dn.border <- dn.border
  cs$Env$theme$rylab <- theme$rylab
  cs$Env$theme$lylab <- theme$lylab
  cs$Env$theme$bg <- theme$col$bg
  cs$Env$theme$grid <- theme$col$grid
  cs$Env$theme$grid2 <- theme$col$grid2
  cs$Env$theme$labels <- "#333333"
  cs$Env$theme$label.bg <- label.bg
  cs$Env$format.labels <- format.labels
  cs$Env$ticks.on <- grid.ticks.on
  cs$Env$grid.ticks.lwd <- theme$grid.ticks.lwd
  cs$Env$type <- type
  cs$Env$axis_ticks <- function(xdata, xsubset) {
    ticks <- diff(axTicksByTime2(xdata[xsubset], labels = FALSE))/2 + 
      last(axTicksByTime2(xdata[xsubset], labels = TRUE), 
        -1)
    if (!theme$coarse.time || length(ticks) == 1) 
      return(unname(ticks))
    if (min(diff(ticks)) < max(strwidth(names(ticks)))) {
      ticks <- unname(ticks)
    }
    ticks
  }
  cs$add(expression(atbt <- axTicksByTime2(xdata[xsubset]), 
    segments(atbt, get_ylim()[[2]][1], atbt, get_ylim()[[2]][2], 
      col = theme$grid, lwd = grid.ticks.lwd), axt <- axis_ticks(xdata, 
      xsubset), text(as.numeric(axt), par("usr")[3] - 
      0.2 * min(strheight(axt)), names(axt), xpd = TRUE, 
      cex = 0.9, pos = 3)), clip = FALSE, expr = TRUE)
  cs$set_frame(-1)
  cs$add_frame(0, ylim = c(0, 1), asp = 0.2)
  cs$set_frame(1)
  cs$add(expression(if (NROW(xdata[xsubset]) < 400) {
    axis(1, at = 1:NROW(xdata[xsubset]), labels = FALSE, 
      col = theme$grid2, tcl = 0.3)
  }), expr = TRUE)
  cs$add(expression(axt <- axTicksByTime(xdata[xsubset], format.labels = format.labels), 
    axis(1, at = axt, labels = names(axt), las = 1, lwd.ticks = 1, 
      mgp = c(3, 1.5, 0), tcl = -0.4, cex.axis = 0.9)), 
    expr = TRUE)
  cs$Env$name <- name
  text.exp <- c(expression(text(1 - 1/3, 0.5, name, font = 2, 
    col = "#444444", offset = 0, cex = 1.1, pos = 4)), expression(text(NROW(xdata[xsubset]), 
    0.5, paste(format(start(xdata[xsubset]), format = '%Y.%m.%d'), 
               format(end(xdata[xsubset]), format = '%Y.%m.%d'), 
      sep = " / "), col = 1, adj = c(0, 0), pos = 2)))
  cs$add(text.exp, env = cs$Env, expr = TRUE)
  cs$set_frame(2)
  cs$Env$axis_labels <- function(xdata, xsubset, scale = 5) {
    axTicksByValue(na.omit(xdata[xsubset]))
  }
  cs$Env$make_pretty_labels <- function(ylim) {
    p <- pretty(ylim, 10)
    p[p > ylim[1] & p < ylim[2]]
  }
  cs$add(expression(assign("alabels", make_pretty_labels(get_ylim(get_frame())[[2]]))), 
    expr = TRUE)
  cs$set_frame(-2)
  cs$add(expression(if (diff(range(xdata[xsubset], na.rm = TRUE)) < 
    50) segments(1, seq(min(xdata[xsubset]%/%1, na.rm = TRUE), 
    max(xdata[xsubset]%/%1, na.rm = TRUE), 1), length(xsubset), 
    seq(min(xdata[xsubset]%/%1, na.rm = TRUE), max(xdata[xsubset]%/%1, 
      na.rm = TRUE), 1), col = theme$grid2, lty = "dotted")), 
    expr = TRUE)
  cs$set_frame(2)
  cs$add(expression(segments(1, alabels, NROW(xdata[xsubset]), 
    alabels, col = theme$grid)), expr = TRUE)
  if (theme$lylab) {
    cs$add(expression(text(1 - 1/3 - max(strwidth(alabels)), 
      alabels, noquote(format(alabels, justify = "right")), 
      col = theme$labels, offset = 0, cex = 0.9, pos = 4, 
      xpd = TRUE)), expr = TRUE)
  }
  if (theme$rylab) {
    cs$add(expression(text(NROW(xdata[xsubset]) + 1/3, alabels, 
      noquote(format(alabels, justify = "right")), col = theme$labels, 
      offset = 0, cex = 0.9, pos = 4, xpd = TRUE)), expr = TRUE)
  }
  cs$set_frame(2)
  cs$add(expression(range.bars(xdata[xsubset], type, 1, fade(theme$line.col, 
    clev), fade(theme$up.col, clev), fade(theme$dn.col, 
    clev), fade(theme$up.border, clev), fade(theme$dn.border, 
    clev))), expr = TRUE)
  assign(".chob", cs, .plotEnv)
  if (!is.null(TA) && nchar(TA) > 0) {
    TA <- parse(text = TA, srcfile = NULL)
    for (ta in seq_along(TA)) {
      cs <- eval(TA[ta], envir = parent.frame())
    }
  }
  assign(".chob", cs, .plotEnv)
  cs
}

environment(plotquant) <- asNamespace("quantmod")
ct <- chart_theme()
ct$format.labels <- ' '
plotquant(BRS, theme = ct)
```

Comment: Thanks for helpful hints! Why can't plotquant()'s text.exp be changed on-the-fly? Editing a file seems incredibly brittle.  Also it would be helpful to combine all of this into one file (like the initial question) so that the results can be easily replicated as I want to be able to run this in a script on any machine, not just one particular machine/environment.

Comment: You cannot rewrite/edit functions from packages in R.This is how R works I'm afraid. The only thing you can do is create your own function and add it to the namespace of the package. Also, the above can be replicated in any kind of machine or environment. You create `plotquant` on your own and it's a function ready to be used anywhere. If you type the name on the console and run it (without brackets),the source code will be revealed.You either save the function in a script and source it or you can use `save` and `load` to save it on the disk and use it. So, all the code will be in one script.

Comment: I updated the answer. As you can see everything is now one script that can be used anywhere.